# Using Reactstrap and Hashrouter, how do you use DropdownItem in the Navbar as a Navlink to other pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I built a simple react app using reactstrap and the Hashrouter function.

- Hashrouter and NavLink  are from react-router-dom
- DropdownItem is from reactstrap

My Navbar is functional but clicking on the dropdown button (DropdownItem) to each page does nothing, while clicking directly on the passed text/NavLink element leads to the intended page. The reason for this is that the text shown in my dropdowns are fully passed NavLink elements which are wrapped in the dropdown button (DropdownItem).

Here is the link passed to the Navbar element

```
      lookupLink={<NavLink to="/Lookup">Lookup</NavLink>}
```

And here is what the Navbar component side of things looks like

```
<DropdownItem>
    {props.lookupLink && props.lookupLink}
</DropdownItem>
```

Image: [Clicking on the blue text works, but anything to the right of the red line does nothing, where I want everything in the black border to act as a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNonk.png)

How would I ensure pressing any part of the entire DropdownItem element acts as a link to my Lookup page?

Appendix:
This is roughly what my index.js file looks like, after removing irrelevant parts of the code

```
<React.StrictMode>
<HashRouter>
    <div>
        <Navbar1 
            lookupLink={<NavLink to="/Lookup">Lookup</NavLink>}
        />
    <div className="content">
        <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <HomePage 
            lookupLink={<NavLink style={{color:"white"}} to="/Lookup">Lookup</NavLink>}
        />} />
    </div>
  </div>
</HashRouter>
</React.StrictMode>
```